# Using QR codes to record results of card sorting exercise

Tags: information-architecture, usability-testing, card-sorting

I have seen that [OptimalSort](https://www.optimalworkshop.com/optimalsort) gives an option to add barcodes to cards. However, this requires paying for OptimalSort and purchasing a barcode scanner. There are many free apps for reading QR codes.

**Can anyone think of a solution for recording the results of a card sort by scanning a QR code that has been printed on each card?**

Comment: sounds like a massive ball ache if you ask me. Write cards on computer>print out>do card sort>scan back in. hmmmm

Comment: This actually might not be a good fit for UX.SE because it seems like a too broad of a question. Might want to narrow the question down; I can foresee too many answers for this question.

Comment: @colmcq Yeah I'm thinking maybe just take photos of the cards in their groups once they have been sorted, then record the results manually in a spreadsheet.

Comment: thats faster than printing them out and scanning them back in. Seems ridiculous.

Comment: Well I'm going to have to type the results back in anyway if I want them in digital format for analysis. I thought quickly scanning the codes could take the same amount of time, and there would be the possibility of having my data ready organised when I came to look at the results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Optimal Workshop. We have actually started work on a mobile app especially for scanning barcodes into OptimalSort, but unfortunately I don't have a release date for you just yet.

You don't actually need a barcode scanner at all. The card numbers are also printed directly below the barcodes and are generally just 1 or 2 digits long. So you can enter them into OptimalSort quite efficiently just using a keyboard.